# Fourth Order ODE, particular solution, using operator method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Problem: $$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}-y=xsin(2x)$$
Using operator method (Notation: $D^n = \frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$)

**Attempt:**
$$y_p=\frac{1}{D^4-1}xsin(2x)$$
So we want the imaginary part of: $$y_p=\frac{1}{D^4-1}xe^{2ix}$$
Using the shift (translation) rule:
$$y_p=e^{2ix}\frac{1}{(D+2i)^4-1}x$$
Expanding:
$$y_p = e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D^4+8iD^3-24D^2-32iD+15}x$$
Factoring 15:
$$y_p = e^{2ix}\frac{1}{15} \frac{1}{1+\frac{D^4+8iD^3-24D^2-32iD}{15}}x$$
$$ \iff y_p = \frac{e^{2ix}}{15} (1-(D^4+8iD^3-24D^2-32iD)+...)x$$
$$ \iff y_p = \frac{1}{15}e^{2ix}(x+32i)$$
$$ \iff y_p = \frac{1}{15} (\cos 2x + i \sin 2x) (x+32i) $$
$$ \iff y_p = \frac{1}{15} [ x \cos 2x +32 i \cos 2x + i x \sin 2x -32 \sin 2x ]$$
Taking the imaginary part only:
$$ \iff y_p = \frac{1}{15} [32  \cos 2x + x \sin 2x]$$

The problem is, when I tried to verify if this function is a solution of the original ODE, it does not satisfy the equality. For instance, the fourth derivative is:
$$\frac{16x \sin 2x}{15} +32 \cos{2x}$$ and subtracting that from y does not yield $x \sin x$.

So how to solve this using operator?
Lastly, is there a "faster" way to solve this rather than using operator method?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me I'd like to use undetermined coefficients method to solve it.

Comment: Because the characteristic equation doesn't have the root $\pm 2i$, if you want to see that, I can write down more detailed in my answer.

Comment: Ohh thats right, I recently have been using variation of parameters and operator method so I forgot about undetermined coefficients method! Thanks! 
Though, if anyone knows why the operator did not work, or where did I go wrong?

Comment: I am not good at using operator method, but I suppose you lost a $\frac{1}{15}$ in the second equation of 'Factoring $15$'.

Comment: So $y_{p}$ should be $$\frac{e^{2ix}}{15}\left(1-\frac{1}{15}(D^4+8iD^3-24D^2-32iD)+\cdots\right)x$$

Comment: :O such a stupid mistake !

You can post any answer so that I can make the question "answered". 
Thank you very much @CunyiNan

Comment: With undetermined coefficients method $y_p=\frac{x\sin2x}{15}+\frac{32\cos2x}{225}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{I was writing this answer when OP replied me in the comment.}$

$\textbf{But I would like to put my solution here for reference.}$

I am not so good at using operator method to solve this type of ODE. However, I think using undetermined coefficients method would be faster.

We've known this ODE has the characteristic equation of $\lambda^4-1=0$, it has four roots $\pm1,\pm i$. The homogeneous equation has a general solution $C_{1}e^{x}+C_{2}e^{-x}+C_{3}\cos x+C_{4}\sin x$.

Note the right term of the inhomogeneous equation has the form $\textbf{polynomial}\times\textbf{trigonometric function}\times e^{0x}$, and the term $\sin 2x$ implied it doesn't have the same root like $\pm i$, so we can set up the special solution $(Ax+B)\sin2x+(Cx+D)\cos2x$. Maybe the direct calculations are annoying(that's why I don't suggest undetermined coefficients method if you know operator method), finally we got the special solution
$$\frac{1}{15}x\sin(2x)+\frac{32}{225}\cos(2x)$$

P.S.: OP has already found the mistake in his attempt, so the answer is just put here for another solution.